# Extjs: Drag panels inside responsiveLayout config

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a panel like admin-dashboard example dashboard in extjs 6 examples with responsiveColumn Layout.
Can I make the child panels draggable from one position to other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly you are trying to achieve something like in this example: [Ext JS Portal](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/classic/portal/index.html).

I haven't had a chance to try it out myself, but this documentation leads me to believe it already supports drag & drop: [Ext.dashboard.Dashboard](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.dashboard.Dashboard.html).

Check those out. They should help you along. Good luck!

Comment: Hello! Is there an option for this in the modern toolkit Extjs 6.5.3?

Comment: It looks like Ext.dashboard.Dashboard is for the classic toolkit only. I can't find anything named 'dashboard' in Modern. I'm sure there's a way to achieve something similar, but i don't know for sure.